# VueJS listening custom events?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, drag-and-drop, vue.js, packery

And I'm trying to figure out how to get Vue listen for custom events (drag and drop). for instance I need to run this event:

```
pckry.on( 'layoutComplete', function( ) {
  pckry.layout();
});
```

Packery lib events
http://packery.metafizzy.co/events.html

my code there: http://codepen.io/Monocle/pen/ZbeBGL

And how to update $data based on changes in the DOM (after reorder elements) ?

Comment: An issue here is the elements never actually reorder, they just reposition themselves. What kind of order are you hoping to get out of them?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a reference to the element. just add an event listener:

```
pckry.addEventListener('layoutComplete', (ev)=> {
        console.log('event~!');
      }, true);
```

you can take a look at this custom event stuff here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener